# Datalab Notebook Answer y/N in prompt

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

In datalab notebook, I having been stuck in answering y/N in the output prompt.

for example,

1. If I use *!pip install somepackage -y* , I can use flag -y to answer yes.
2. However, when I try to copy some table from one dataset to another, it the destination table already exists, the prompt comes out to ask me to replace the destination table? but I can't type y in notebook, then the notebook will be stuck there.

   ```
   !bq cp project1:dataset1.table1 project2:dataset2.table2
   pop:
   cp: replace project2:dataset2.table2? (y/N)
   ```

There is no flag I can set to overwrite existing destination table, does anyone has any idea how to deal with this kind of situation? Otherwise, the notebook will keep running unless I force to stop it.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Problem SOLVED!  1. use < !yes | bq cp project1:dataset1.table1 project2:dataset2.table2 > to repalce the destination table'  2. use < !yes n | bq cp ... > to not replace.   Thank you.

Comment: <!echo n | command>  also works for answering No. thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding questioner's comment (not mine) as the answer so that this doesn't appear as an unanswered question.
Problem SOLVED! 1. use < !yes | bq cp project1:dataset1.ta‌​ble1 project2:dataset2.ta‌​ble2 > to repalce the destination table' 2. use < !yes n | bq cp ... > to not replace. Thank you.